# Windows 10 Repairing Loop after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd

I have a 250 GB SSD  and a 2TB HDD. 1 Year Ago I moved my windows to the ssd and everything was working fine.

Today I decided to install Ubuntu alongside with windows. During installation, I choose it to install on the SSD and would take a few GBS. after installation. Now Ubuntu is working fine, but I keep getting the Windows repairing loop.

I tried many solutions that are out there and not worked. I even tried "Reset and keep my files" option but it did't run.

I was thinking about moving all data from SSD to HDD (I don't wanna lose my SSD data), but on Ubuntu I can't see all drives. I only can see a small portion of my SSD which is dedicated to Ubuntu and a partition of my HDD?

**Note**: when I used the ntfs command with the ssd, it gave me the error:

```
Run lists overlap. 
Cannot merge: Numerical result out of range ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: 
Numerical result out of range Failed to load $MFT: 
Numerical result out of range Failed to mount '/dev/sdb6': 
Numerical result out of range
```

How I can solve this problem and in worst case scenario how not to lose all my data?

Comment: "I tried many solutions and non[e] worked" does not provide much useful troubleshooting information. Edit your question to provide details that we can work with. Also tell us exactly how you prepared for installing Ubuntu - a link to instructions you followed would be very helpful. If you skipped steps or didn't understand steps or received a mysterious error message, say so. That's exactly the information we need to help you best.

Comment: Advice: Back up ALL your data immediately. You should have backed up everything before starting to install Ubuntu. Installing an Operating System is *risky*.

Comment: How can I backup my entire SSD drive, as I said I cant see all of it on Ubuntu

Comment: If you "can't see all drives," then ask yourself "*Why not? And exactly which partitions or drives?*" The most common reasons are failing to disable Windows FastBoot and failing to disable Windows Dynamic Disks -- both of which are proprietary Windows products, can only be disabled from within Windows, and disabling them are part of normal preparation for dual-boot...did you check for those and disable them? There are other possible reasons beyond those.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I watched few tutorials on how to do  dual boot, they did not mention that at all

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to do:

- install ntfs-3g: `sudo apt install ntfs-3g` if not installed
- determine what is your SSD and HDD partitions: run `sudo fdisk -l` and look for hdd device with the biggest size and ssd device with smaller size.
- create folder for your hdd mount point: `sudo mkdir /mnt/hdd`
- create folder for you ssd windows partition mount point: `sudo mkdir /mnt/ssd`
- mount your partitions exchanging X by your actual partition letters and numbers you could find in `fdisk -l` and `ls /dev/sd*` output:

  ```
  sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sdaX /mnt/ssd
  sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sdbX /mnt/hdd
  ```
- add records about your partitions into `/etc/fstab`:

  ```
  /dev/sdaX /mnt/ssd ntfs-3g permissions,users,auto,locale=en_US.utf8 0 2
  /dev/sdbX /mnt/hdd ntfs-3g permissions,users,auto,locale=en_US.utf8 0 2
  ```
- Also, you could try Windows LiveCD to boot and check if your Windows 10 partition is accessible from it or connect your SSD drive to another windows PC.

Comment: when I  used the ntfs command with the ssd, it gave me this error 
 " Run lists overlap. Cannot merge: Numerical result out of range
ntfs_mapping_pairs_decompress() failed: Numerical result out of range
Failed to load $MFT: Numerical result out of range
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb6': Numerical result out of range"
and When I ran it on the hdd it mounted the one partition (645G)of the entire hdd, than I can already see.My guess in now I can only see 29G of ssd and 645G of the Hdd, and and those are dedicated to Ubuntu, while the rest of the space  is for windows and I cant access or see it

Comment: @BodaSadallah try Windows LiveCD